# How can i generate random ips from 0.0.0.0/0 range

Tags: python

Here is my code so far.

```
import requests, sys, concurrent.futures, random

ip = ".".join(str(random.randint(0, 255)) for ip in range(4))

def scan(ip):
     headers = {'user-agent': 'Keurig K575 Coffee Maker'}
     r = requests.get('http://' + ip + ':80' + sys.argv[1], headers=headers, timeout=0.5)
     print(r.url, r.status_code, r.headers['Server'])

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
     executor.map(scan, ip)
```

Comment: How is this failing to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import socket
import struct
socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(1, 0xffffffff)))
```

This will generate random IPs in range `0.0.0.0` ~ `255.255.255.255`

In order to generate within a range use `for n in range(0x01020408, 0x08040201)` [this will generate in range *1.2.4.8 and 8.4.2.1*.]

You can also use Fake Apache Login, but I doubt that will help your case.

```
from faker import Faker  
fakeIP = Faker()  
ip_addr = fakeIP.ipv4()
```

Answer (score 1):

ipcalc lets you generate IPs

```py
import ipcalc
import random
#This generates 4294967296 ips
ips = ipcalc.Network('0.0.0.0/0')


n = random.randint(1,4294967296)
#select a random ip
print(ips[n])
```